# HTTP Response Header "Content-Type" configured incorrectly Unity WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

How to solve. I created map in Unity and built it for WebGL. When I put the map on browser the warning message below appeared. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLOBF.png

Comment: The error nis probably true. Did you configure your webserver as unity tells you to? It is not what you might guess

Comment: I'm not sure, but I will set it up as per Unity's configuration